# Protection of the formatting of a spreadsheet

Tags: excel-2003

I am creating an Expense Reimbursement spreasheet that will allow users to input their expenditures and the spreadsheet will automatically add all of the columns.  I have protected the spreadsheet so that they can only enter information in unprotected cells.  The problem I am having is: how do I protect the sheet so that when someone prints the form, they cannot change the print layout?  (i.e. they should not be able to change the page layout, or change the margins, etc.)  How can I protect the spreadsheet from someone printing it on legal paper, or putting it on 2 pages, etc?

Answer (score 1):

There is, far as I can tell, no way to lock the layout...  But how are you with VBA?

The `Worksheets("SheetName").PageSetup` object will allow you to specify all of the page setup properties, and if you were to put these specifications in the Workbook's `Workbook_BeforePrint` and `Workbook_BeforeSave` subroutines, Excel would 'reset' your specifications right before it printed (and saved), ensuring that your layout was honoured.